# General maximization/minimization technique without calculus?

Tags: calculus, optimization, contest-math

I know that you can use derivatives to find the minimum/maximum of a function. However, sometimes it is very difficult or too long. For [example](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2000_AMC_10_Problems/Problem_20),

> [image]

In the problem above, there are 3 variables, and on the AMC 10 you don't exactly have the time for fancy calculus. Is there another general technique for cases like this? Thanks!

Comment: You would not be able to solve this problem by calculus, because it is an integer problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = AMC+AM+AC+MC$, and let $x=A+1$, $y=M+1$, $z=C+1$.  We notice that 
$$xyz = S+A+M+C+1 = S+10+1=S+11$$
so we can maximize $S$ by maximizing $xyz$ subject to the constraint $x+y+z =13$, since $A+1+M+1+C+1=13$.

For the moment let's suppose $x,y,z$ can be non-integer.  Then by the AM-GM inequality, we know $xyz$ is maximized when $x=y=z$. Since $x+y+z=13$, this yields $x=y=z=13/3$, with $xyz=(13/3)^3 \approx 81.4$, corresponding to $S =xyz-11\approx 70.4$.  So with integer constraints, we know we can't do better than $S=70$; that eliminates choices (D) and (E).

If we look for integer values near $13/3$ with sum $13$, it's natural to try $x=y=4$, $z=5$, which yields $xyz=80$, corresponding to $S=80-11=69$.  So the answer is (C).

Answer (score 1):

For this specific problem, I just thought, that amc + am + mc + ac thing looks a lot like multiplication, I bet it behaves like that. And when splitting an interval to make a product (choose a + b = 1 to maximize ab) the maximal split is half-and-half, so I figured for splitting it into 3 parts to make a product the maximal split would be around third-third-third. So choose 3-3-4. And lo and behold, it gives one of the answers.

With multiple choice, you can kinda just guess.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. So far, your answer contains some heuristic arguments for why 3-3-4 might be the best solution for obtaining a maximum value. I think your answer should also contain a rigorous proof why 3-3-4 is the best solution.